# Select specific columns from the stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure in other database which is maintained by other team. Assume that it is currently returning 3 columns, and my system only needs those 3 columns
but the other team can add few more columns for their own use which is causing my system to fail.

Other database SP

```
ALTER PROCEDURE FirstSP 

AS
BEGIN
    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #A (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(200), Amount VARCHAR(100), TestColumn INT)
    INSERT INTO #A VALUES
    (1,'ABC','23',1), (2,'CDF','35454',2), (3,'hjhj','9809909',3)

    SELECT * FROM #A

    DROP TABLE #A
  
END
GO
```

And below is my query, which was only expecting 3 columns from the source

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(200), Amount INT)

INSERT INTO #MyTable
EXEC dbo.FirstSP;  

SELECT * FROM #MyTable

DROP TABLE #MyTable
```

Is there any way I can provide the column list?

This is what I am trying but it seems that I can't use server name as the parameter

```
DECLARE @ServerName VARCHAR(100) = @@SERVERNAME

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(@ServerName,'EXEC dbo.FirstSP')
```

My whole problem is to just select required columns from the SP. SP can have many columns in future.

Comment: Is converting the sp into a tvf an option?  Alternatively  you can `select * into` a temp table, all the columns returned by `FirstSP` and then select only what you want from the temp table in your app.

Comment: How can I do SELECT * INTO ? If that would work then I am good. I am trying this but this is not working SELECT * INTO #A
EXEC dbo.FirstSP

Comment: You would do `CREATE TABLE {TableName}... INSERT INTO {TAbleName} EXEC {YOurProcedure}` @Zerotoinfinity . But really, if you only want certain columns, then you probably won't want a procedure and want an inline table-value function. A Procedure isn't designed to have its data consumed in the same way as a `SELECT`.

Comment: @Larnu but the problem is that I am not sure about the new column addition in future. In my example. SP has 4 columns where I am expecting only 3

Comment: If your Procedure returns 4 columns, and you're expecting 3, then your expectations are you wrong. You should be expecting 4.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I know but the problem is that the other SP is being used by a different department and they can increase the number of columns. So, idea is to keep our process unaffected with the change; as I had mentioned in my question

Comment: I would suggest that you have your own procedure then, or (like mentioned) migrate the procedure to an inline TVF (like mentioned) and then you can *literally* just `SELECT` the columns you want. If your procedures definition is in flux, then, in honest, sounds like a problem unto itself you need to address.

Comment: Does your `@@ServerName` change frequently? If you can substitute the name instead of using a variable in `OpenQuery` then there isn't a problem. If it does change frequently can you create a _linked server_ so that you can use a stable name to refer to the dancing server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Replace <SERVERNAME>\<INSTANCENAME>], <DATABASENAME> with your names
*/  ------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- First, enable Data Access (One time only)    
EXEC sp_serveroption '<SERVERNAME>\<INSTANCENAME>', 'DATA ACCESS', TRUE;

-- Then SELECT just the fields you need
SELECT  ID, Name, Amount
FROM    OPENQUERY([<SERVERNAME>\<INSTANCENAME>], 'EXEC <DATABASENAME>.dbo.FirstSP')
```

Comment: To add up for the future user; first I used below query to create a self loop linked server then use the queries mentioned in the answer EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LOOPBACK', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'SQLNCLI11', @datasrc=N'DEVSQL01'

Comment: Article: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/running-openquery-with-local-database-and-server-credentials

Comment: you can update the answer with my comment. This worked for me. First I created the self loop linked server then I used your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask the team that develops the stored procedure to create a parameter "Team" or something and slightly change the sp so that it will return the expected columns based on this parameter.

A more cumbersome solution is to use this stored procedure the get the colum names of the (first) result returned by the sp.

```
sp_describe_first_result_set 'dbo.usp_mySp';
```

And then use the result to create some dynamic SQL.